# How to use plotmeans or geom_errorbar for a Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

Good day

I am trying to plot the means and 95% confidence intervals for my shiny webpage but I can't seem to get it right.

I would like output similar to this
[image]

I have tried two methods

1. Using geom_errorbar
   Here I tried creating a summary table that calculates the 95% CI and then plotting from there.
   My code follows

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("questionnaire"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("question", "Choose a question",
                  colnames(Data[,3:(ncol(Data)-1)]))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("meanCI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ci <- reactive({
    groupwiseMean(input$question ~ Date,
                  data   = Data,
                  conf   = 0.95,
                  digits = 3)
  })
  output$meanCI <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(ci, aes(x=Date, y=Mean)) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Trad.lower, ymax=Trad.upper), width=.1) +
      geom_point()

  )


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But it gives me this error,

> `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class reactiveExpr/reactive

2. Option 2 was to use plotmeans from the `gplot` package

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("questionnaire"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("question", "Choose a question",
                  colnames(Data[,3:(ncol(Data)-1)]))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("meanCI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$meanCI <- renderPlot(
plotmeans(input$question~Data$Date, connect = FALSE)

  )


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But it results is this error,

> variable lengths differ (found for 'Data$Date')

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(rcompanion)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("questionnaire"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("question", "Choose a question",
                  colnames(iris)[1:4])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("meanCI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  ci <- reactive({
    groupwiseMean(data = iris,
                  var = input[["question"]],
                  group = "Species",
                  conf   = 0.95,
                  digits = 3)
  })
  output[["meanCI"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(ci(), aes(x=Species, y=Mean)) + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Trad.lower, ymax=Trad.upper), width=.1) +
      geom_point()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your main error is the missing parentheses in `ggplot(ci(), ......`. The other one is `input$question ~ Date`, which doesn't work because `input$question` is a character string.